How to configure the Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS strongswan gui network manager client only on mschapv2?
I have Ubuntu 22.04.4 and a separate ikev2 vpn with the mschapv2 method.
I installed strongswan and network-manager-strongswan, which has a gui, configured encryption algorithms, specified the server, user certificate, password. And judging by the logs, it does not use mschapv2, which is the only one supported by the vpn server.
cat /etc/strongswan.d/charon/eap-mschapv2.conf 
eap-mschapv2 {
    load = yes
}

cat /etc/strongswan.d/charon/eap-dynamic.conf 
eap-dynamic {
    preferred = eap-mschapv2
}

nmcli vpn.data "..., refuse-mschapv2 = yes,..." not work.
 generating IKE_AUTH request 1 [ IDi N(INIT_CONTACT) CERTREQ CPRQ(ADDR ADDR6 DNS NBNS DNS6) SA TSi TSr N(MOBIKE_SUP) N(ADD_4_ADDR) N(ADD_4_ADDR) N(EAP_ONLY) N(MSG_ID_SYN_SUP) ]
 charon-nm: 14[NET] sending packet: from client[37045] to server[4500] (368 bytes)
 charon-nm: 15[NET] received packet: from server[4500] to client[37045] (1248 bytes)
 charon-nm: 15[ENC] parsed IKE_AUTH response 1 [ IDr CERT AUTH EAP/REQ/ID ]
 charon-nm: 15[IKE] received end entity cert "CN=server"
 charon-nm: 15[CFG]   using trusted certificate "CN=server"
 charon-nm: 15[IKE] authentication of 'server' with RSA signature successful
 server requested EAP_IDENTITY (id 0xEB), sending 'login'
 charon-nm: 08[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH request 2 [ EAP/RES/ID ]
 charon-nm: 08[NET] sending packet: from client[46734] to server[4500] (80 bytes)
 charon-nm: 09[NET] received packet: from server[4500] to client[46734] (80 bytes)
 charon-nm: 09[ENC] parsed IKE_AUTH response 2 [ EAP/REQ/PEAP ]
 charon-nm: 09[IKE] server requested EAP_PEAP authentication (id 0xEC)
 charon-nm: 09[IKE] EAP method not supported, sending EAP_NAK
 charon-nm: 09[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH request 3 [ EAP/RES/NAK ]
 charon-nm: 09[NET] sending packet: from client[46734] to server[4500] (80 bytes)
 charon-nm: 10[NET] received packet: from server[4500] to client[46734] (80 bytes)
 charon-nm: 10[ENC] parsed IKE_AUTH response 3 [ EAP/REQ/TLS ]
 charon-nm: 10[IKE] server requested EAP_TLS authentication (id 0xED)
 charon-nm: 10[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH request 4 [ EAP/RES/TLS ]
 charon-nm: 10[NET] sending packet: from client[46734] to server[4500] (224 bytes)
charon-nm: 11[NET] received packet: from server[4500] to client[46734] (1088 bytes

UPD: I change strongswan.cfg, I turned off everything except EAP-MSCHAPv2, And it didn't help for me
cat /etc/strongswan.conf 
charon {
    load_modular = yes
    plugins {
        include strongswan.d/charon/*.conf
                }
}

charon-nm {
    plugins {
        eap-dynamic {
            load = no
        }
        eap-tls {
            load = no
        }
        eap-peap {
            load = no
        }
        eap-nak {
            load = no
        }
        eap-md5 {
            load = no
        }
        eap-gtc {
            load = no
        }
        eap-radius {
            load = no
        }
        eap-tnc {
            load = no
        }
        eap-ttls {
            load = no
        }
        eap-aka {
            load = no
        }
        eap-identity {
            load = no
        }
        eap-mschapv2 {
            load = yes
        }

    }
}


include strongswan.d/*.conf


charon-nm: 15[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH request 1 [ IDi N(INIT_CONTACT) CERTREQ CPRQ(ADDR ADDR6 DNS NBNS DNS6) SA TSi TSr N(MOBIKE_SUP) N(ADD_4_ADDR) N(ADD_4_ADDR) N(EAP_ONLY) N(MSG_ID_SYN_SUP) ]
charon-nm: 15[NET] sending packet: from client[43716] to server[4500] (368 bytes)
charon-nm: 01[NET] received packet: from server[4500] to client[43716] (1248 bytes)
charon-nm: 01[ENC] parsed IKE_AUTH response 1 [ IDr CERT AUTH EAP/REQ/ID ]
charon-nm: 01[IKE] received end entity cert "CN=server"
charon-nm: 01[CFG]   using trusted certificate "CN=server"
charon-nm: 01[IKE] authentication of 'server' with RSA signature successful
charon-nm: 01[IKE] server requested EAP_IDENTITY (id 0x67), sending 'login'
charon-nm: 01[IKE] EAP_IDENTITY not supported, sending EAP_NAK
charon-nm: 01[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH request 2 [ EAP/RES/NAK ]
charon-nm: 01[NET] sending packet: from client[43716] to server[4500] (80 bytes)
charon-nm: 08[IKE] retransmit 1 of request with message ID 2
charon-nm: 08[NET] sending packet: from client[43716] to server[4500] (80 bytes)
charon-nm: 09[IKE] retransmit 2 of request with message ID 2
charon-nm: 09[NET] sending packet: from client[43716] to server[4500] (80 bytes)
charon-nm: 10[IKE] retransmit 3 of request with message ID 2
charon-nm: 10[NET] sending packet: from client[43716] to server[4500] (80 bytes)
charon-nm: 11[IKE] retransmit 4 of request with message ID 2
charon-nm: 11[NET] sending packet: from client[43716] to server[4500] (80 bytes)
NetworkManager[1115]: <warn>  [1720101416.3885] vpn[0x628ba897c140,cbdefa88-2ae3-447e-b83c-c305efa288f5,"VPN 11"]: connect timeout exceeded
charon-nm[7940]: Connect timer expired, disconnecting.
charon-nm: 12[IKE] destroying IKE_SA in state CONNECTING without notification


Note that eap-dynamic is a server-side plugin, so even if it is loaded it has no effect on clients. Also, the settings in /etc/strongswan.d/charon only affect the charon or charon-systemd daemons, not the charon-nm daemon that's used by NetworkManager.

nmcli vpn.data "..., refuse-mschapv2 = yes,..."

Where did you get that from? These are not options for strongSwan's NetworkManager plugin. And I'd think an option that's named refuse-mschapv2 would disable that authentication method, not enable/force it.

And judging by the logs, it does not use mschapv2, which is the only one supported by the vpn server.

That's definitely not true, the server initiates the EAP-PEAP method (which can tunnel EAP-MSCHAPv2, by the way). But because you don't have the eap-peap plugin loaded, the client sends an EAP-Nak message with the supported EAP methods. This apparently includes EAP-TLS, which is the next method the server tries to initiate. So it supports at least these two other methods as well. Otherwise, it would just start by initiating EAP-MSCHAPv2 and you wouldn't have this issue.
You can disable the eap-tls plugin to avoid it getting proposed in the EAP-Nak message by adding the following to /etc/strongswan.conf:
charon-nm {
  plugins {
    eap-tls {
      load = no
    }
  }
}


I change strongswan.cfg, I turned off everything except EAP-MSCHAPv2, And it didn't help for me. eap-tls {
load = no
}
eap-peap {
load = no
}
eap-nak {
load = no
}
eap-md5 {
load = no
}
eap-gtc {
load = no
}
eap-radius {
load = no
}
eap-tnc {
load = no
}
eap-ttls {
load = no
}
eap-aka {
load = no
}
eap-identity {
load = no
}
eap-mschapv2 {
load = yes
}


You need the eap-identity plugin as well.

I turn up eap-identity, everything is still not working, the output of logs has not changed

Check again, because the log messages should definitely be different if that plugin is loaded (it currently explicitly complains that the EAP-Identity method is not available).

Thank you for your time, I will make logs again, and I will attach, maybe I did not notice the differences, I will also attach the config.
